# Silk Performer - recalulating a specific time period

Tags: silk-performer

Is it possible to have Silk Performer recalculate results based on a specific time period from testing?  What I am seeing is a spike at the end of my test.  This needs investigated, but I would like to show that prior to that spike, the average time was good.  Because of this spike I am getting a couple seconds higher - at least that is my assumption right now.  I would like to show that before the spike the times are good.
Here is what I am seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Silk Performance Explorer there is a resample option under results.  You can set the specific time period for calculation there.